# COUNTIFS with day and time

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have some dates that look something like this

[image]

and basically what I want to do is use a COUNTIF that counts everything for the 04/02/2021 but I have the problem that there are times involved in this so =COUNTIF(MySheet!X:X,&B4) does not work. What can I do so that it includes everything for that date regardless of the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use COUTNIFS and bookend the date:

```
=COUNTIFS(MySheet!X:X,">="D3,MySheet!X:X,"<"&D3+1)
```

Comment: At the moment I have the dates in a cell, so what I was trying to do is more like =COUNTIF(MySheet!X:X,D3). How can I change this so it works this way instead?

Comment: why is the +1 added in this case?

Comment: Dates are integers (Number of days since `12/31/1899`). the Time is a decimal portion of a day. So a flat date is just the integer, if the date does not have a time decimal it is midnight so we book end midnight to midnight.